# R scatter plot - different colors for text and markers

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have problem like that - I want to make scatter plot where markers have different colors. But the problem is names of markers - it have another colors than dots.

Is there any way to make it consistent?

Here is code example:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

data<-data.table(c('A','B','C'),c(1,2,3),c(3,2,1))

plot_ly(data,x=data$V2, y=data$V3,type='scatter',marker=list(size=10)) %>%
add_text(text=data$V1,textposition = "top right",color=data$V1) %>%
layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change content in **t** as you want.

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

data<-data.table(c('A','B','C'),c(1,2,3),c(3,2,1))

t <- list(
          family = "sans serif",
          size = 14,
          color = toRGB("grey50"))

plot_ly(data,x=data$V2, y=data$V3,type='scatter',marker=list(size=10)) %>%
add_text(textfont = t, text=data$V1,textposition = "top right",color=data$V1) %>%
layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

Comment: Here all text has the same color. And how do to have the same color for each marker and text?